# Update Each Row In a Column Based on a Value from Updation in Another Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table by the name of tblInvManager which have Following Columns

Table Name: tblInvManager

**InvNo | Customer Name | InvAmount | AllInvTotal**
1     |    Cust A     |    50,000   |     50,000
2     |    Cust A     |    15,000   |     65,000
3     |    Cust A     |    25,000   |     90,000
4     |    Cust A     |    40,000   |    130,000
5     |    Cust B     |    10,000   |     10,000
6     |    Cust B     |    35,000   |     45,000
7     |    Cust B     |    80,000   |    125,000
8     |    Cust C     |    12,000   |    12,000
9     |    Cust C     |    18,000   |     30,000

For example If value of Invoice Number:1 in the above table is updated from 50,000 to 25,000, I want to update the AllInvTotal Columns As per the changes 
so my new table after the update of Invoice Amount will be as Follow:

**Expected Result**

**InvNo | Customer Name | InvAmount | AllInvTotal**

1     |    Cust A     |    25,000   |     25,000
2     |    Cust A     |    15,000   |     40,000
3     |    Cust A     |    25,000   |     65,000
4     |    Cust A     |    40,000   |    105,000
5     |    Cust B     |    10,000   |     10,000
6     |    Cust B     |    35,000   |     45,000
7     |    Cust B     |    80,000   |    125,000
8     |    Cust C     |    12,000   |     12,000
9     |    Cust C     |    18,000   |     30,000

I have made Following Query but i am not able to do so. Can Someome Please help me:

```
DECLARE @Inv_No VARCHAR(MAX)  
DECLARE @LCRef VARCHAR(MAX)  
DECLARE @InvTotal DECIMAL(18,6)  
DECLARE @AllInvTotal DECIMAL(18,6)  

SET @AllInvTotal = 0  

DECLARE InvManagerCursor CURSOR  
FOR SELECT InvNo_InvMan, LCRef_InvMan, InvAmt_InvMan FROM tblInvManager  
FOR UPDATE OF AllInv_InvMan  
OPEN InvManagerCursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM InvManagerCursor INTO @InvNo, @LCRef, @InvTotal  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

SET @AllInvTotal += @InvTotal  

Update tblInvManager   
SET AllInv_InvMan = @AllInvTotal  
WHERE CURRENT OF InvManagerCursor  

FETCH NEXT FROM InvManagerCursor INTO @InvNo, @LCRef, @InvTotal  
END  
CLOSE InvManagerCursor  
DEALLOCATE InvManagerCursor
```

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here. But your cursor syntax is not correct. What is "FOR UPDATE OF..."???? This looks like a running total which can be done in a set based approach instead of RBAR (row by agonizing row).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* your problem can be solved with a simple update statement executed after the update you want to do in a specific row:

```
UPDATE tblInvManager SET AllInvTotal = (SELECT SUM(InvAmount) FROM 
tblInvManager  AS T WHERE t.Customer_Name = O.Customer_Name and T.InvNo <= O.InvNo) 
FROM tblInvManager  AS O WHERE O.Customer_Name = 'Cust A'
```

This will update the `AllInvTotal` column for al rows where `Customer Name` is `Cust A`.

The following test code returned the expected output with the sample data you provided:

```
declare @tblInvManager table (
    InvNo INT,
    Customer_Name NVARCHAR(20),
    InvAmount MONEY, 
    AllInvTotal MONEY)

INSERT INTO @tblInvManager VALUES (1,'Cust A ',50000,50000)
INSERT INTO @tblInvManager VALUES (2,'Cust A ',15000,65000)
INSERT INTO @tblInvManager VALUES (3,'Cust A ',25000,90000)
INSERT INTO @tblInvManager VALUES (4,'Cust A ',40000,130000)
INSERT INTO @tblInvManager VALUES (5,'Cust B ',10000,10000)
INSERT INTO @tblInvManager VALUES (6,'Cust B ',35000,45000)
INSERT INTO @tblInvManager VALUES (7,'Cust B ',80000,125000)
INSERT INTO @tblInvManager VALUES (8,'Cust C ',12000,12000)
INSERT INTO @tblInvManager VALUES (9,'Cust C ',18000,30000)

-- Sample Data
SELECT * FROM @tblInvManager

UPDATE @tblInvManager SET InvAmount = 25000 WHERE InvNo = 1
UPDATE @tblInvManager SET AllInvTotal = (SELECT SUM(InvAmount) 
FROM @tblInvManager  AS T WHERE t.Customer_Name = O.Customer_Name and T.InvNo <= O.InvNo) 
FROM @tblInvManager  AS O WHERE O.Customer_Name = 'Cust A'

--Expected Output
SELECT * FROM @tblInvManager
```

**Sample Data**

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Emilio Ceroleni .... You are great, it worked my problem is solved. Thanks a million